# AJAX POST to WCF web config need another set of eyes/mind

Tags: wcf, post, asp.net-ajax

For some reason I'm not able to get a very simple AJAX post to my web service (svc) to work.
I'm sure it's a problem with my web.config, but I tried everything I can find online.

In "MyService.svc" if is use

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method ="POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat  =WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    public string DoWork()
    {
        string result = "did it";
        //result = test;

        return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(result)); ;
    }
```

where DoWork only returns a value, Ajax succeeds.  However, if I pass a parameter to DoWork(string test)
Ajax returns an error.  Bad Request.

My ajax is:

```
function DoTest() {
                testData = { "test": "Hello" };
                var jsonData = JSON.stringify(testData);
                var POSTURL = "MyService.svc/DoWork";

                //alert(jsonData);
                //alert(POSTURL);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: POSTURL,
                    datatype: "json",
                    data: jsonData,
                    ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("success: " + result.d);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert("Opps: " + xhr + " " + status + " " + error);

                    }
                })

            }

        });
```

This is in my web.config:

```
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
          binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyService" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I need another set of eyes on this otherwise simple program.  Thanks

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

"Bad Request" is usually an error in the request format. You can use the help document in WCF to view the request format. If you want to enable the help document, you need to change the WebMessageBodyStyle to bare:

```
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle =WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
```

Then enable the help document in the configuration file:

```
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ESEndPointBehavior">
                 <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
```

**View the requested format in the browser, you need to send the data in its format.**

Comment: Hum. I made some changes and now I'm getting a 500 Error: ServiceActivationException.

Answer (score 0):

I removed an extra <endpoint address="" I had in my revision.  The service call is being made from AJAX now.  Phew.  This WCF works great when it's working, and very difficult to diagnose when it does not work.  Thanks for listening and good luck to everyone.